# Cleaning a column from one sheet into another

Tags: excel

Sorry if the title is off, but I have no way of making this short.

I have an excel file with 2 sheets: Sheet1 has the first column filled with data, but in a random pattern (ex: 6 consecutive cells are with data, 6 are without, other of the following alternate; basically there is no way of knowing if the next cell has data or not). I want to copy the first column from Sheet1 into Sheet2 without any blank cells or duplicate ones (the order of the data can be maintained or be changed as the result of the formula).

Can this be done without any coding?

Comment: Why not filter the column to exclude blanks and remove duplicates and then copy the filtered and de-duplicated data? No coding, no formula just Excel's built-in tools for data manipulation.

Comment: @DMM - I didn't want to directly use filters since it removes rows. However, I found out how to get unique data, so it's that. I'll still have to use filters to remove a few rows, just hoping it's ok with my boss.

Comment: Filtering does not remove rows, it just hides them from view. You can always copy the column to a new blank worksheet, filter and remove duplicates etc and then copy the results to your desired target location. After doing this just delete the worksheet you performed the manipulation on. The original Sheet1 will be left entirely unchanged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your `Sheet1` is as follows

[image]

Then in `Cell A2` of `Sheet2` enter the following formula

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!A$2:A$50,SMALL(INDEX(NOT(ISBLANK(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$50))*ROW($A$1:$A$49),0),COUNTBLANK(Sheet1!$A$2:$A$50)+ROW($A1))),"")
```

Drag/Copy down as required. Change range in formula as needed. See image for reference.

[image]

***EDIT :***

To get unique values from `Column A` of `Sheet2` enter below formula in `Cell B2` of `Sheet2`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$20,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$20),0,0),0)),"")
```

Comment: So you're assuming that the data is in numerical/alphabetical order with or without gaps. Problem is the data I have it not in order, and I cannot simply sort it in Sheet1 due to the meaning behind their arrangement. So I have to do it whilst keeping their current arrangement, while ALSO removing duplicates (which do appear).
I tried your formula as it is, with the range adjustments, and it didn't work.

Comment: @Pishti - No I am not assuming data is in any order. That's just a dummy data I've used. Overlooked removing duplicates. See edit in answer.

Comment: For some reason the first formula doesn't work, however, I did manage to apply the second formula directly on Column A from Sheet1 and I've applied a filter from Excel's tools. Hopefully my boss will be ok with it. Thx for the help.

Comment: @Pishti - Can you share the screen shot of first formula with data not working.

Comment: @Pishti - Formula looks okay, can you make sure that the cells are empty by checking `=LEN(A86)`

Comment: ok.. apparently every single "blank" cell actually had 3 spaces in it... no wonder it didn't work. Thx

Comment: @Pishti - If this solved your problem kindly accept the solution as answer by clicking tick mark at the top left of my answer.

Comment: Ok, sorry, still new to this site.

Comment: @Pishti - No problem!